# What dovecot web administration software do you use?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a customer-oriented web administration application for Dovecot (and Exim, if it matters), but a lot of the software I've found so far is either buggy and doesn't work, or is an abandoned Sourceforge project, or has tortured documentation that doesn't accurately describe how to install it (and doesn't work).

We're used to Qmailadmin here, and that is basically exactly what we need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend [Postfix Admin](http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/). Despite its name it is really a generic web interface for administrating an MTA. Dovecot usually doesn't need special data except the user credentials which can be fetched from the same database your MTA uses. If you want a rather Exim-centric web interface you should take a look at [vexim](http://silverwraith.com/vexim/) which sadly hasn't seen an update in a while.

As a matter of fact, any web interface for Postfix or Exim (probably using a relational database as backend for user credentials and metadata, such as maildir paths) should do the trick for you.

Comment: +1 for postfixadmin. It's very good but has some limitations.

Comment: I've actually found this quite useful. Also, since I know my way around PHP a bit, any shortcomings, incompatibilities or bugs are easy for me to fix, so I have.

Answer (score 0):

I use ISPwebAdmin
its very basic but simple :)
http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/manage-email-accounts